# How to cater the list of scheduled time in an Alarm Manager to push notifications

Tags: java, android, sqlite, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am trying to retrieve the list of time stored in **Sqlite**  (it has both hours and minutes) into the alarm manager to perform a reminder via a notification. My approach was to loop all the scheduled time stored in Sqlite into the alarm manager to perform notifications basing on the list of time stored,but the notification doesn't beep.

***But when i specify one time (hour and minute) it works . Below is the code sample which works, but i don't want this:***

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListRemainder.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ListRemainder.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**But when it comes to loop several time schedules it doesn't work,and it's the approach i want,  below is the code sample,what am i missing?**

```
//listOfTime is the one which contains the list of stored scheduled time in Sqlite.
for (int i = 0; i < listOfTime.size(); i++) {
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(listOfTime.get(i).toString().substring(0, 2));
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(listOfTime.get(i).toString().substring(3));
    System.out.print("Hour : " + hour + " Minute : " + minute);
    Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm On");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListRemainder.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ListRemainder.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: What happens if a unique PendingIntent is created on each iteration (Give the 2nd parameter in getBroadcast a unique value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype for getBroadcast looks like:

```
getBroadcast(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
```

Setting a unique 'requestCode' for each PendingIntent should allow for the scheduling of multiple alarms:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, uniqueValue, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

For guaranteed wake-up for user critical alarms:

```
void setAlarmClock (AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info, 
            PendingIntent operation)
```

From the Docs:
"Schedule an alarm that represents an alarm clock, which will be used to notify the user when it goes off. The expectation is that when this alarm triggers, the application will further wake up the device to tell the user about the alarm -- turning on the screen, playing a sound, vibrating, etc. As such, the system will typically also use the information supplied here to tell the user about this upcoming alarm if appropriate.

Due to the nature of this kind of alarm, similar to setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int, long, PendingIntent), these alarms will be allowed to trigger even if the system is in a low-power idle (a.k.a. doze) mode."

To summarise:

- Use setAlarmClock to wakeup the device to present info to the user.
- Use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle to do work in the background that must be done during doze. However, the firing of these alarms may be subject to delays ranging from 1 minute to 15 minutes roughly.
- Use FCM to wake up the device in real time from a remote application. In practise, many apps should use FCM instead of setExactAndAllowWhileIdle if possible.
- Use setExact if exact syncing during doze is not important. Also,  use setExact on pre-API 21 devices instead of setAlarmClock or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle...

Lutaaya's final solution:

```
AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: so my line should look this **pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ListRemainder.this, i, myIntent, 0);**

Comment: Yes looks good. The flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT is not needed. It could become useful if extras are added in the future.

Comment: Np. It might be best to do the initial tests with the device charging (or the screen left on) so that the code can be verified without Doze coming into play. But as you may already know, it is no longer possible to reliably wake up a device via the AlarmManager on a chosen HOUR and MIN of the day. High priority cloud messages need to be used instead.

Comment: @Ellestar, which High priority cloud messaging should i use please? because am developing a small project which reminds diabetics people to take their insulin.

Comment: I would use FCM [Firebase Cloud Messaging]. The Alarm Manager became less reliable for scheduling starting with Android 6. The system is now free to delay alarms and break WakeLocks. There are Doze maintenance windows when alarms can fire, but I would assume that medication reminders are too critical to tolerate delays.

Comment: Not sure if you've done much Firebase, but Android Studio -> Tools -> Firebase -> Cloud Messaging is good for getting a project started.

Comment: So do these cloud messaging platforms like firebase help to fire alarms without internet connection?

Comment: Good point. I think that you want setAlarmClock API 21 for this type of app. Pre-21, setExact should work without any complications for the most part...

Comment: what do you mean by setExact please ,and where should i place it? my current code is  this      `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ListRemainder.this, i, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

Comment: They are both APIs in the AlarmManager. I'm saying that instead of calling "alarmManager.set()" use "alarmManager.setAlarmClock()" for Android 6+[API: 21+] devices. For older devices, it is okay to use "AlarmManager.setExact" because setExact will not be affected by doze restrictions on those old devices...

Comment: Hey , i used setAlarmClock() , but what should i place in **AlarmClockInfo** parameter

Comment: Well, i ended up using this  `alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent), pendingIntent);`

Comment: Cool. Sorry I should never have brought up FCM. I was thinking of my services that wake up to sync data in the background. Those are subject to long delays up to ~15 minutes even if setExactAndAllowWhileIdle is used, but for user facing alarms setAlarmClock is the way to go...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170708/discussion-between-elletlar-and-lutaaya-huzaifah-idris).